# Replacing old Nutone vent fan, light and heater unit in bathroom

Tags: light, exhaust-fan

I have three single pole separate switches in the bathroom downstairs. I have three /2 cables coming from downstairs going into the attic. I can get the light to work but not the vent fan and heater.

What am I doing wrong? The old unit worked for 22 years. I wired the old one but can’t seem to get this one done.

Comment: Welcome. We'll need you to provide more detail. I assume the three cables are all switch loops, but you haven't said where power comes in. Please revise to be more clear about the wiring scenario.

Comment: 3 separate /2 cables could only be legal if the power is at the device and these are switch loops as Isherwood mentioned. Where is the power coming in? How are each of the devices connected, a switch loop is one place where a white wire is connected to a hot.

Comment: Post the pictures you took before you took everything apart, then pics of what you've got now.

Comment: Model # of old and new?

Answer (score -1):

If power is at the switch, bring two cables to the unit. You’ll use the two black wires (one for heater, for vent) and one of the white wires (coded blue for the light) as your hot wire looped at the switches and all the other white wires connected together as your neutral

Comment: What does "one of the white wires (coded blue for the light) as your hot" mean? You start talking about having power at the switch (which is required by code since 2008, but not required earlier, then "coding" a white wire blue as a hot? You don't repurpose the neutral at the switch box if you've got always hot coming into the switch box. Sounds like you're combining two different things into one and endangering people.